# Ruby rescue all exceptions except MyException

Tags: ruby, exception

In Ruby, is it possible to rescue all exceptions except for a specified one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not as such no. But you can rescue all exceptions and reraise the exception if it is a MyException.

Comment: You're not supposed to rescue all exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-a-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Comment: @WillSheppard I would argue that this depends entirely on what your code is doing.

Answer (score 55):

```
begin

rescue MyException
  raise #to reraise the same exception without changing it
rescue Exception => e
  #do something with e
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your problem, I'd suggest Ken Bloom's answer.

However, I'd like to know more about why you're doing it.

Are you worried about a really severe exception, and not wanting to rescue that one, but allow less severe exceptions to be rescued?

In that case, I'd make my custom exception inherit from `Exception` rather than `StandardError` and then have

```
begin
  do_risky_stuff
rescue # Not rescue Exception
  handle_less_serious_stuff
end
```